# how to use java stream to group fields and create a summary

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

```
public class Call {
    private String status;
    private String callName;
}
```

I have a list of calls  and i have to create a summary, like this:

```
public class CallSummary {
    private String callName;
    private List<ItemSummary> items;
}
public class itemSummary {
    private String status;
    private Integer percentage;
}
```

My goal is show a percentage of calls with some status
like :

```
INBOUND_CALL : {
FAILED = 30%
SUCCESS = 70%
}
```

how can i do it using java 8 stream and Collectors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the grouping would be to nest is in such a way that you have a call name and then status based count lookup available. I would also suggest using an enumeration for the status

```
enum CallStatus {
    FAILED, SUCCESS
}
```

and adapting it in other classes as

```
class Call {
    private CallStatus status;
    private String callName;
}
```

Then you can implement a nested grouping and start off with an intermediate result such as:

```
List<Call> sampleCalls = List.of(new Call(CallStatus.SUCCESS,"naman"),new Call(CallStatus.FAILED,"naman"),
        new Call(CallStatus.SUCCESS,"diego"), new Call(CallStatus.FAILED,"diego"), new Call(CallStatus.SUCCESS,"diego"));

Map<String, Map<CallStatus, Long>> groupedMap = sampleCalls.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Call::getCallName,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Call::getStatus, Collectors.counting())));
```

which would give you an output of

```
{diego={FAILED=1, SUCCESS=2}, naman={FAILED=1, SUCCESS=1}}
```

and you can further evaluate the percentages as well. (though representing them in `Integer` might lose precision depending on how you evaluate them further.)

---

To solve it further, you can keep another `Map` for the name-based count lookup as:

```
Map<String, Long> nameBasedCount = calls.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Call::getCallName, Collectors.counting()));
```

and further, compute summaries of type `CallSummary` in a `List` as :

```
List<CallSummary> summaries = groupedMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new CallSummary(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(en -> new ItemSummary(en.getKey(), percentage(en.getValue(),
                        nameBasedCount.get(entry.getKey()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `percentage` count be implemented by you using the signature `int percentage(long val, long total)` aligned with the datatype chosen in `ItemSummary` as well.

Sample result:

```
[
CallSummary(callName=diego, items=[ItemSummary(status=FAILED, percentage=33), ItemSummary(status=SUCCESS, percentage=66)]), 
CallSummary(callName=naman, items=[ItemSummary(status=FAILED, percentage=50), ItemSummary(status=SUCCESS, percentage=50)])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following collects to a status -> percent map which you can then convert to you output model. This code assumes a `getStatus` method.

```
List<Call> calls;
Map<String,Double> statusPercents = calls.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Call::getStatus,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), 
            n -> 100.0 * n / calls.size())));
```

I realise this code is a bit hard to read. The chain of collectors group the calls by status and then counts each group and finally converts to a percent. You could (arguably) make it more readable by having interim variables for the collectors:

```
var percentFunction = n -> 100.0 * n / calls.size();
var collectPercent = collectingAndThen(count(), percentFunction);
var collectStatusPercentMap = groupingBy(Call::getStatus, collectPercent);
```

You also want to group by call name but that's really just the same thing - using `groupingBy` and then reducing the list of calls to a `CallSummary`.