# how can i create a summary using collectors

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

```
public class Call {
    private String status;
    private String callName;
    private int duration;
    private int waitedTime;


}
```

I have a list of calls and i have to create a summary, like this:

```
public class CallSummary {
    private String callName;
    private List<ItemSummary> items;
    private int averageDuration;
    private int averageWaitedTime
}
```

```
public class itemSummary {
    private String status;
    private Integer percentage;
}
```

My goal is show a summary like :

```
{
    callname:"sac",
    averageDuration:"60",
    averageWaitedTime:"10",
    items:{
        status:"failed",
        percentage:"40"
        status:"answered","60" 
    }
}
```

how can i do it using java 8 stream and Collectors ?

Comment: Why do you want to use streams and collectors? What's the intended benefit? You'd have to write your own collector for that.

Comment: There is [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html)

Comment: Did you start with the previous [question's answerr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60332944/1746118) and reach somewhere? Then what was it that got you stuck? Further hint, you can calculate per call name average call duration using the following statement `Map<String, Double> callNameAverage = sampleCalls.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Call::getCallName, Collectors.averagingInt(Call::getDuration)));`

Comment: @deHaar `IntSummaryStatistics` are good when for the same Integer attribute one needs different summary aspects and not when there are multiple attributes involved with varied calculations. (Custom collector could do the needful though.)

Comment: @Naman OK, thanks... good to know. Was just a first shot, so no answer, just a comment...

Comment: @Naman After finishing the previous demand, this new demand arose, I wanted to do something more dynamic in which through my grouping I already create the CallSummary list